# Switching 12 V when power is on/off from a 4.5 V source

Tags: switches, relay, 12v

Is there a switch for 12 V that will turn off/on when power is either off/on from another source? Example: I have an LED controller for lights. It only pushes 4.5 volts, which won’t supply all my lights.

So in theory I need a switch that is connected to direct power (battery) to the group of lights. But then lights will be on all the time. But I’m asking if there is a switch that I can use on my controller that will shut the power direct from battery to lights and my 4.5 V out put on my controller when either send power through or shut the switch.

Comment: Welcome! How much 12 V current are we talking about? AC or DC? Have you looked into a relay or PMOS switch?

Comment: N-channel MOSFET with serie resistor and pull-down. Positive voltage of LEDs connect to 12V, negative to Drain of NMOS. NMOS Source to ground.

Comment: I’ve looked into some relays in switches but wasn’t sure what to get. Or the name i need to search to look for the correct one.  The LEDS function properly through my power probe 12v. But the controllers 4.5v won’t even turn them on. It will turn a few on if i i connect a few. It’s not an extreme amount of voltage though.

Comment: It's OK to ask "What kind of component performs X task?" but not on-topic to ask "What brand or part number do you recommend?" See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I’m not asking a brand or part number. Just to get knowledge about what component falls into the category that I’m thinking about/using. I appreciate the help as I get it folks! I have no idea what switch’s do what. But i am learning

Comment: get a mosfet switch module that breaks out all the connections to terminals. They can be used more-or-less just like a relay, but will last forever, switch instantly, and you won't have that annoying  relay click.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you need is a **[relay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay)**. Find a relay with a 4.5 V compatible coil, and contacts rated for 12 V (at whatever current you require). It can perform the task of switching the 12 V load based on 4.5 V at its coil.

The following schematic shows the electrical connections proposed. Note that data or signal from controller to lights is not shown. I also have the controller and relay coil wired in parallel. If you want the controller to directly control the relay, you would need to make sure it has an output capable of driving a relay coil. If your controller is something like an Arduino, for example, you would probably want instead to use a MOSFET to switch either the relay or the entire 12 V load, depending on a lot of information that was not included in your question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp6IYw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Relay may work but you missed some caveats. What about lifespan of relay when driving using PWM? To me it sounds like task for NMOS rather than relay.

Comment: @Misaz Consider the original post. The OP only talks about basic on/off functionality. If they are trying to perform some kind of PWM on the low voltage side and have it apply to the load as well, they should have mentioned it.

Comment: I’d be satisfied with a component to switch 4.5 v to 12v or a relay/switch component that will shut on/off the power directly from battery to my lights when 4.5v is sent or shut off the the switch/relay

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a double pole switch - one pole/switch circuit to control the 4.5 volt source and the second pole to control the 12 volt source.

More details on the 4.5 volt controller and the overall circuit configuration would help to determine the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

An SPST toggle switch and a 4.5 V DC relay should serve the purpose.

[image]